# "Git Bash Here" creates a bash terminal with a nonfunctional version of git

Tags: windows, bash, git, admin, git-bash

I've suddenly started experiencing an issue on Windows 10 where right clicking in a git repo folder and selecting **"Git Bash Here"** returns a bash terminal that has a *useless* version of git in it.

I say that this version of git is *useless* because you can enter git commands, but nothing seems to happen. (`git log` is the only exception to this, as it works fine, showing the history of commits.) All of the other `git <commands>` return absolutely nothing. Not even an error is returned.

Things worth noting:

- Sometimes (maybe every time?), before an unsuccessful git command is 'finished running,' a quick black prompt is seen flashing on the screen for a fraction of a second.
- Right clicking and selecting **Git GUI Here** prompts me with an error window

  - Window title: "**git-gui: fatal error**"
  - Window content: "**Cannot parse Git version string:**"
- Reinstalling does NOT solve the issue

Another coworker started experiencing this same issue a week before I did, so now I'm left wondering if a slow roll out of a Windows update was to blame, as we have the same desktop environment and IT department supporting it.

**Question:
How can I restore the functionality of "*right click* Git Bash Here" in Windows 10?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is resolved by altering compatibility mode on `git-bash.exe` (located in `C:\Program Files\Git` by default), specifically setting it to always run as administrator.

This can be done by right clicking the executable (again, `git-bash.exe`), clicking Properties, the Compatibility tab, and then checking "Run this program as an administrator". Click **Apply**, then **OK**, and you should be all set.

NOTE: Apply these same steps to `git-gui.exe`, located by default in `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`, to fix the issue stated with the **Git GUI Here** selection in explorer's right click window.